# jqgrid: How to find the selected column when the columns are dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a chunk of javascript that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listident = "#list3";
    // ...
    var children = //get one or more "child" objects as JSONArray
    $.each(children, function(i){
        jobGridColNames.push(children[i] + "");
        jobGridColModel.push({name: children[i], index: children[i], align: 'center',
                       editable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkboxFormatter', 
                       formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editoptions: { value:"true:false"}, sortable: true
                       });
    });
    // ...
    $("#compareButton").button({text: true}).click(function(){
        var selectedRows = getSelectedRows("list3");
        if(selectedRows.length == 0){
            alert("Please select at least one row");
            return;
        }
        $.each(selectedRows,function(i, row){
            // ...?  Here is where I need help
        });
    });
});

checkboxFormatter: function checkboxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if(cellvalue == "different"){
        return "<input offval='on' type='checkbox' value='false' >";
    }else{
        return cellvalue
    }
}
```

I don't know in advance how many columns I will have, nor will I know the name of the column. All I know is that each dynamic column will have either a checkbox or some text in it.

When I click the #compareButton, I need to know the row and column of all the checkboxes that were checked anywhere in the grid (there might be multiple checkboxes checked in a  row).  I don't see anything in the row object that tells me what column I am looking at when I find all the checked checkboxes.

The only thing I can think of is to have an onChecked event that saves the rowXcolumn pair to a local variable.  That seems gross.  But I can't find anything else that might work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're using a custom formatter, so i think you shouldn't use the editable feature. BUT you need to specify the unformatter. are the checkbox all in the same columns?

Comment: Thanks.  1)  We got the same result  regardless of how editable was set.  2)  We aren't using an unformatter (didn't even know about it).  I'll look into that.  3)  Not quite sure what you mean by "all in the same columns".  What we have is a grid where every cell has either a checkbox or some text.

Comment: the unformatter is the opposite of the formatter, it will convert the cell html in a valid value for your rowdata.
i see an error in the `$.each` call, you are pushing the columns for each row in the array. so if you have somthing like this `[ [ 'pos(0,0)' , 'pos(0,1)' ], [ 'pos(1,0)' , 'pos(1,1)' ] ]` you will end up having 4 columns. is that your expected result?